# One time login using shared preferences?

Tags: android, authentication, sharedpreferences

This may be duplicate question but still i cant find a solution for this as am new for android am using sharedpreferences for login activity my requirement it should not display the login page unless we logout how can i do this so far what i have tried is

Main activity:

```
package first.service.precision.servicefirst;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.net.ConnectivityManager;
import android.net.NetworkInfo;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
  //  public EditText password, userName;
    Button login, resister;
    ProgressBar progressbar;

public static String s1,s2;
    TextView tv;
    public static final String pref="login";
    String TAG = "Fails";
    String url = "http://172.16.7.203/sfAppServices/SF_UserLogin.svc";
    private ModelLogin Result;
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences;
   private SharedPreferences sharedpreferences;
  //  public static final String MyPREFERENCES = "MyPrefs" ;
    protected void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        SharedPreferences shared=getSharedPreferences(pref,0);
        Boolean logins=shared.getBoolean("do",false);

        if(logins){
            Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Main2Activity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }


        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
   final EditText     userName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtEmployeeCode);
        final EditText      password = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.password);


     login = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnsignin);
        userName.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.colorfoucs);
        ConnectivityManager cn = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo nf = cn.getActiveNetworkInfo();
        if (nf != null && nf.isConnected() == true) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Network Available", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        else
        {
            showAlertDialog(MainActivity.this, "No Network", "Please Check Your Network Connectivity", true);
        }
        //}

        final ConnectionDetector cd = new ConnectionDetector(getApplicationContext());

        login.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {

            public void onClick(View v) {
              //  sharedpreferences = getSharedPreferences(MyPREFERENCES, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                progressbar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
                progressbar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                s1 = userName.getText().toString();
                s2 = password.getText().toString();
         SharedPreferences     sharedPreferences=getSharedPreferences(pref, 0);
                SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
                editor.putBoolean("do",true);
                 editor.putString("yog",s1);
                editor.putString("pass",s2);
                editor.commit();

                if (s1.equals("")) {
                    userName.setError("Enter Employee Code");
                }
                if (s2.equals("")) {
                    password.setError("Enter Password");

                }
                Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Main2Activity.class);
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Welcome_"  +""+  s1, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                startActivity(intent);
/*                RestAdapter adapter = new RestAdapter.Builder().setEndpoint(url).build();
                RetrofitRest retro = adapter.create(RetrofitRest.class);
                retro.getResult(s1, s2, new Callback<ModelLogin>() {
                    @Override
                    public void success(ModelLogin modelLogin, Response response) {
                        if (modelLogin.getResult().equals(1)||modelLogin.getModuleID().equals(1)) {


                            progressbar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                        }
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void failure(RetrofitError error) {
                        progressbar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Login Fails", LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                });*/


            }

        });

      //  if(sharedpreferences.contains(s1)) {
          //


    }















    public void showAlertDialog(Context context, String title, String message, Boolean status) {
        AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(context).create();

        // Setting Dialog Title
        alertDialog.setTitle(title);

        // Setting Dialog Message
        alertDialog.setMessage(message);

        // Setting alert dialog icon


        // Setting OK Button
        alertDialog.setButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            }
        });

        // Showing Alert Message
        alertDialog.show();
    }

}















    public void showAlertDialog(Context context, String title, String message, Boolean status) {
        AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(context).create();

        // Setting Dialog Title
        alertDialog.setTitle(title);

        // Setting Dialog Message
        alertDialog.setMessage(message);

        // Setting alert dialog icon


        // Setting OK Button
        alertDialog.setButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            }
        });

        // Showing Alert Message
        alertDialog.show();
    }

}
```

its just misbehaving like for first time its going to home screen from second time redirecting to new login screen .don't know where am doing mistake it would be very helpful if somebody find solution for my answer

Comment: can you define "misbehaving" more clearly? What is working, what is not and where the problem is?

Comment: always in login screen not moving it to home screen am i doing it in right way

Comment: even if there is any appropriate way you can share

Comment: for first time it going to second screen from another time it starts to new login screen

Comment: Where is your `LoginActivity`? You should check for existing values in the `SharedPreferences`, if so, launch the `MainActivity`.

Comment: my mainactivity is login one

Comment: above code is login page

Comment: am i doing it in right way

Comment: do you got it worked..?

Comment: no in mean while time i was on other work now i came back to it

Answer (score 3):

Try making your launcher activity without a layout, then put your pref checking here and start your next activity.

- Launcher Activity (if credentials exists) -> MainActivity
- Launcher Activity (if credentials doesn't exists) -> LoginActivity

StartActivity.java

```
public class StartActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private static final String PREF_LOGIN = "LOGIN_PREF";
private static final String KEY_CREDENTIALS = "LOGIN_CREDENTIALS";


@Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    SharedPreferences preferences = getSharedPreferences(PREF_LOGIN, MODE_PRIVATE);

    Intent intent = null;
    if(preferences.contains(KEY_CREDENTIALS)){              //if user is currently logged in;
        intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
    }else {                                                 //if user is not yet logged in;
        intent = new Intent(this, LoginActivity.class);
    }
    startActivity(intent);
}

}
```

LoginActivity.java

```
public class LoginActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

public static final String PREF_LOGIN = "LOGIN_PREF";
public static final String KEY_CREDENTIALS = "LOGIN_CREDENTIALS";

private Button loginButton;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

    //...

    loginButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            //call login api...


            //on your sucess callback; we save the credentials...
            /*
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getSharedPreferences(PREF_LOGIN, MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
            editor.putString(KEY_CREDENTIALS, "DUMMY CREDENTIALS");
            editor.commit();
            */

            //on your failure callback; we clear the credentials...

            /*
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getSharedPreferences(PREF_LOGIN, MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
            editor.clear();
            editor.commit();
            */
        }


    });
}

}
```

Comment: Login process will remain in `LoginActivity`

Answer (score 1):

You can try the following code:

You can have a boolean variable as shown below and check it solves your problem:

inside login.setOnClickListener have the following code:

```
 SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("MyLogin.txt", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
                editor.putBoolean("FirstLogin", true);
                editor.commit();
```

and in onCreate have the following code:

```
SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("MyLogin.txt", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
         Boolean loginCheck = sharedPreferences.getBoolean("FirstLogin", false);
              if (loginCheck){

                  intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Main2Activity.class);
                   startActivity(intent);
              }
```

Comment: If my answer helped you, can you please select it as an answer.

Comment: hello keshav then where to post my user entered value in edit text

Comment: It will be better if you use database for that... Y don't you use database??

Comment: later il try it to make connection with retrofit

Comment: Have a simple registration page. Then you can check for login. In your case it is hard coded.

Comment: I didn't get you. In shared preference if your file name is same then the value will be over written

Comment: for first two time its directly moved to main activity without login page then from third time its coming again into login pagte

Comment: Debug the code by adding break point and check,.it should not happen like that. You mean to say when you launch the application, every third time login screen is shown??

Answer (score 0):

Using shared preferences you can use any key as a flag to check if its login for the first time. For example if you take a key logged_in is a key then set it false or null at the start . When user logs in first time then set it to some value like true or key value you want . For the next time check if this flag is true or the value you set previously and id it is set , no need to login.

//Code snippet for the same:

```
SharedPreferences pref= getSharedPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);
Editor editor= pref.edit();
editor.putBoolean("some key" ,false);
//Now when user logs in :
editor.put("some key", true);
//Now for the next login:
if(pref.getBoolean("some key")==true){

// Do not ask for login
}else{
//Ask for login
}
```

Comment: can you share some snippet with user entered value in edittext

Comment: for first two times its working after that value gets cleared

Answer (score 0):

> oncreate do like that,suppose welcome screen is your luncher activity

```
private static final String PREF_LOGIN = "LOGIN_PREF";
private static final String USER_EMAIL = "EMAIL_ADDRESS";
private static final String USER_PASSWORD = "PASSWORD";
SharedPreferences preferences = getSharedPreferences(PREF_LOGIN, MODE_PRIVATE);
           Intent intent = null; 
            if(preferences.contains(USER_EMAIL)&&preferences.contains(USER_PASSWORD)){              
                    intent = new Intent(WelcomeScreen.this,MainMenu.class);//if login
                }else {                                             
                    intent = new Intent(WelcomeScreen.this,LoginScreen.class);//if not login
                }
                startActivity(intent);
                WelcomeScreen.this.finish()
```

> now on your login activity

```
@Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {//supose response from server
            if(response.contains("sucess")) {

                SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getSharedPreferences(PREF_LOGIN, MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
                editor.putString(USER_EMAIL,email);
                editor.putString(USER_PASSWORD,passworde);
                editor.commit();

             startActivity(new Intent(LoginScreen.this,MainMenu.class));
            }
        }
```

> now for log out if user want, form shared preferences

```
    @Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    int id=item.getItemId();
    if(id==R.id.logout)
    {

        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getSharedPreferences("LOGIN_PREF",getApplicationContext().MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
        editor.clear();
        editor.commit();



                if (editor.commit()) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Logout Successfully", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                    startActivity(new Intent(MainMenu.this, LoginScreen.class));//open login activity on successful logout 
                }

    }
    return true;
}
```